# C# Best Timer type for always control

Tags: c#, timer

I have a project like task scheduler. So I should check the date and If is there a task at that moment do something. But Im not sure whict type of Timer rhat I should use etc Threading Timer and Callback or Timers.Timer and Tick Event?

Thanks for kindly responses

Comment: There are benefits and negatives to anything. There are many many questions on SO pertaining to timers from both `Timers.Timer` and Threading timers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to see for yourself which timer you need, especially in a thread safe environment. A good way of finding out is checking this table for your preferences:

[image]

A detailed guide based on this table can be found here.
[MSDN Magazine | Timers in .Net](https://web.archive.org/web/20150329101415/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx)